# LeftOuterJoin for Beam in Python

Tags: python, apache-beam

It seems like currently there is no implementation for Joins (e.g. LeftOuterJoin) in Beam Python.

For Java there is `org.apache.beam.sdk.extensions.joinlibrary`, but it seems like no extensions are yet available for Python. Is there any roadmap to implement extensions?

Would it then make sense to reimplement joinlibrary in Python or how else would one get LeftOuterJoin?

Comment: I'm holding off on answering whether there are any alternatives, but for the roadmap part of your question: You'll probably have better luck asking about roadmaps on the Beam developer or user mailing lists (see [Contact Us](https://beam.apache.org/community/contact-us/)).

Comment: If you're dealing with structured data that you can define a [schema](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#what-is-a-schema) for - Python's [SqlTransform](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/current/apache_beam.transforms.sql.html) (which actually uses Java SQL and Java's join library under the hood), or the [DataFrame API](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/dsls/dataframes/overview/) should both be able to do a left outer join.

Answer (score 0):

There is not-officially implemented library for left/right/inner/outer Join in  Python. It's good and ready to use.

https://github.com/pavan-kattamuri/dataflow_joins/blob/master/custom_transforms/joins.py

- Example: https://github.com/pavan-kattamuri/dataflow_joins/blob/master/test.py